# Android: Update Widget From Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget

I'm developing a simple stickynote app, but i have a problem with managing widgets.

I have created the `WidgetProvider` class (`AppWidgetProvider`) and the `EditWidget` class (`Activity`) for editing text.

How can i do to open `EditWidget` activity when I click on the widget and after entering the text, update the widget with the text ?

Each widget created will have a different text and then each widget is unique.

What is the best solution for develop this app ?

My code is:

--- WidgetProvider ---

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
          public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
            for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);                  
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.update, "Click for insert text"
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
            super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
          }
}
```

--- EditActivity ---

```
public class EditActivity extends Activity {

EditText edt_txt;
int appWidgetId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);

    edt_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_txt);    

    Intent launchIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = launchIntent.getExtras();
    appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.save) {        

        String s = String.valueOf(edt_txt.getText());

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
          Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), WidgetProvider.class);
          clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), appWidgetId, clickIntent, 0);
          views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.update, s);
          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        finish();
    }
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly but let's try:

You do not need to start another activity to update your field, just put an attribute in your XML object:

android:onClick="myFunction"

At your code, do this:

```
public void myFunction(View v){
//instantiate your object here and update the object
}
```

Comment: Probably I didn't explain well, now I enter my code that doesn't work.